# Rust cannot move out of dereference pointer

Tags: pointers, rust

I try to run this code:

```
impl FibHeap {
fn insert(&mut self, key: int) -> () {
    let new_node = Some(box create_node(key, None, None));

        match self.min{
            Some(ref mut t) => t.right = new_node,
            None => (),
        };
        println!("{}",get_right(self.min));
    }
}
fn get_right(e: Option<Box<Node>>) -> Option<Box<Node>> {
    match e {
        Some(t) => t.right,
        None => None,
    }
}
```

And get error

```
error: cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer
println!("{}",get_right(self.min));
              ^
```

I dont understand why I get this problem, and what I must use to avoid problem.

Comment: Can we have the full struct/impl block so we can compile and check the other methods used there or a simplified example (preferably to paste in playpen)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that `get_right()` accepts `Option<Box<Node>>`, while it should really accept `Option<&Node>` and return `Option<&Node>` as well. The call site should be also changed appropriately.

Here is the explanation. `Box<T>` is a heap-allocated box. It obeys value semantics (that is, it behaves like plain `T` except that it has associated destructor so it is always moved, never copied). Hence passing just `Box<T>` into a function means giving up ownership of the value and *moving* it into the function. However, it is not what you really want and neither can do here. `get_right()` function only queries the existing structure, so it does not need ownership. And if ownership is not needed, then references are the answer. Moreover, it is just impossible to move the `self.min` into a function, because `self.min` is accessed through `self`, which is a borrowed pointer. However, you can't move out from a borrowed data, it is one of the basic safety guarantees provided by the compiler.

Change your `get_right()` definition to something like this:

```
fn get_right(e: Option<&Node>) -> Option<&Node> {
    e.and_then(|n| n.right.as_ref().map(|r| &**r))
}
```

Then `println!()` call should be changed to this:

```
println!("{}", get_right(self.min.map(|r| &**r))
```

Here is what happens here. In order to obtain `Option<&Node>` from `Option<Box<Node>>` you need to apply the "conversion" to insides of the original `Option`. There is a method exactly for that, called `map()`. However, `map()` takes its target by value, which would mean moving `Box<Node>` into the closure. However, we only want to borrow `Node`, so first we need to go from `Option<Box<Node>>` to `Option<&Box<Node>>` in order for `map()` to work.

`Option<T>` has a method, `as_ref()`, which takes its target by reference and returns `Option<&T>`, a possible reference to the internals of the option. In our case it would be `Option<&Box<Node>>`. Now this value can be safely `map()`ped over since it contains a reference and a reference can be freely moved without affecting the original value.

So, next, `map(|r| &**r)` is a conversion from `Option<&Box<Node>>` to `Option<&Node>`. The closure argument is applied to the internals of the option if they are present, otherwise `None` is just passed through. `&**r` should be read inside out: `&(*(*r))`, that is, first we dereference `&Box<Node>`, obtaining `Box<Node>`, then we dereference the latter, obtaining just `Node`, and then we take a reference to it, finally getting `&Node`. Because these reference/dereference operations are juxtaposed, there is no movement/copying involved. So, we got an optional reference to a `Node`, `Option<&Node>`.

You can see that similar thing happens in `get_right()` function. However, there is also a new method, `and_then()` is called. It is equivalent to what you have written in `get_right()` initially: if its target is `None`, it returns `None`, otherwise it returns the result of `Option`-returning closure passed as its argument:

```
fn and_then<U>(self, f: |T| -> Option<U>) -> Option<U> {
    match self {
        Some(e) => f(e),
        None => None
    }
}
```

I strongly suggest reading [the official guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html) which explains what ownership and borrowing are and how to use them, because these are the very foundation of Rust language and it is very important to grasp them in order to be productive with Rust.